# Converting a shell script to a function in .bashrc [shell quits]

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script which I would like to convert to a function which can be included in `.bashrc`. Apart from `#!/bin/bash`, the shell script consists of the content of the following function:

```
pdfMerge () {
    ## usage
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` infile_1.pdf infile_2.pdf ... outfile.pdf"
    exit 0
    fi
    ## main
    ARGS=("$@") # determine all arguments
    outfile=${ARGS[-1]} # get the last argument
    unset ARGS[${#ARGS[@]}-1] # drop it from the array
    exec gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=$outfile "${ARGS[@]}" # call gs
}
```

It already runs and combines given pdf files with ghostscript. However, the shell always exits after the function is called (also if no arguments are given). How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script is designed to run as a standalone executable, and so exit when it is done. If you want to use it as a function, you need to remove the two elements which enforce this behaviour: `exit 0` (replace it with `return`) and `exec` in front of the call to `gs -dBATCH ...`:

```
pdfMerge () {
    ## usage
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME infile_1.pdf infile_2.pdf ... outfile.pdf"
        return
    fi
    ## main
    ARGS=("$@") # determine all arguments
    outfile=${ARGS[-1]} # get the last argument
    unset ARGS[${#ARGS[@]}-1] # drop it from the array
    gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=$outfile "${ARGS[@]}" # call gs
}
```

Comment: Hi NCao, thanks for helping. This works great except that after calling `pdfMerge` with no arguments, the part after `if...` is executed as well. This leads to `bash: ARGS: bad array subscript` `bash: [0-1]: bad array subscript` `**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.` How can one "gently" quit the function after the `echo`?

Comment: @MariusHofert I forgot a `return` statement indeed, answer updated.

Comment: very good, thanks a lot! `basename $0` should probably also be replaced by just "pdfMerge"

Comment: You can use `$FUNCNAME` too.